# Solution to $xy\,dx-(x^2+y^2)\,dy=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find the general solution to this differential equation, can anyone help?
$$xy\,dx-(x^2+y^2)\,dy=0$$

Comment: Have you tried the exactness test ? What have you tried ??

Comment: It's a homogeneous differential equation.

Comment: Well if I hit this into Wolfram|Alpha I get$$y=\pm\frac x{\sqrt{W(Kx^2)}}$$where $K$ is an arbitrary constant and $W(x)$ is Lambert's W function.

Answer (score 1):

$$(xy) dx-(x^2+y^2)dy = 0$$

Let $F(x,y) = xy$ and let $G(x,y) = x^2+y^2$

Now consider a function $u(x,y) = 0$

Then $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial u}{\partial y}dy = 0 $$

So $$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}}$$

If $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial G}{\partial x}$, then $u(x,y)$ is a solution

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = x \neq \frac{\partial G}{\partial x} = -2x$

So consider an integrating factor $\lambda:$

$$(\lambda xy)dx -\lambda(x^2+y^2)dy = 0$$

We want to have $\lambda$ such that:

$$\frac{\partial \lambda F}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial \lambda G}{\partial x}$$

First let's try $\lambda$ as a function of $x$:

$$\implies \lambda\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = \lambda\frac{\partial  G}{\partial x}+G\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial x}$$

Substituting in we get:

$$\lambda x = -2\lambda x -(x^2+y^2)\frac{d \lambda}{dx}$$

$$3\lambda x +(x^2+y^2)\frac{d \lambda}{dx} = 0$$ - and stuck - try instead $\lambda(y)$

$$\implies \lambda \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} + F\frac{\partial \lambda}{\partial y} = \lambda \frac{\partial G}{\partial x}$$

Substituting in:

$$\lambda x +xy \frac{d \lambda}{dy} = -\lambda \cdot 2x$$

$$3\lambda x +xy \frac{d \lambda}{dy} = 0$$

$$x(3\lambda + y\frac{d \lambda}{dy}) = 0$$

$$\frac{d \lambda}{dy} = \frac{-3\lambda}{y}$$

$$\implies \ln \lambda = -3\ln y + c \implies \lambda = Ae^{\ln y^{-3}} = \frac{A}{y^3}$$

Letting $A = 1$

Then we have $\lambda (y) = \frac{1}{y^3}$

$$(\frac{x}{y^2})dx -(\frac{x^2}{y^3}+\frac{1}{y})dy = 0$$

Now this is in exact form.

So we have that $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{x}{y^2}$$

$$\implies u = \frac{x^2}{2y^2} + f(y) + c_{1}$$

We also have that  $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -(\frac{x^2}{y^3}+\frac{1}{y})$$

Now taking the partial derivative of our expression of $u$ with respect to $y$:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = -\frac{x^2}{y^3} + \frac{\partial f(y)}{\partial y}$$

Then comparing these two we can see that:

$$\frac{\partial f(y)}{\partial y} = -\frac{1}{y}$$

$$f(y) = -\ln|y|$$

Then our final solution is: $$u(x,y) = \frac{x^2}{2y^2}-\ln|y|+c_{1} = 0$$

$$\implies x^2 = 2y^2\ln |y| + 2c_{1}y^2$$

$$x^2 = y^2 \ln(y^2) + \ln (c_{2}) y^2$$, with $\ln c_{2} = 2c_{1}$

Then $$x^2= y^2(\ln(y^2) + \ln c_{2})$$

$$\implies x^2 = y^2\ln(c_{2}y^2)$$

Comment: @JakeF That answer follows from what I had, I edited my answer to get the answer in that form.